# Kstreams how to restrict creating intermediate topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-security

Is there a way can a operations team restrict application teams from creating kafka stream intermediate topics on kafka cluster?

Comment: probably [helps](https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/security.html#streams-developer-guide-security)

Comment: see [this link](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/security.html)  as well

Answer (score 1):

Kafka provides [authorisation mechanisms](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz) and more precisely, a pluggable `Authorizer`. 
You can either use the simple `Authorizer` implementation which is provided by Kafka by including the following configuration in `server.properties`

```
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
```

or you can create your own class that implements [`Authorizer`](http://(https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/security/auth/Authorizer.scala)) Interface. Again, you'd need to provide the `authorizer.class.name` in `server.properties` broker configuration file.

When an authorizer is configured, access to resources is limited to Super Users and therefore if a resource has no associated ACLs, then the access is restricted only to these Super Users. In order to define super users, you simply need to include them in the `server.properties` configuration;

```
super.users=User:Bob;User:Alice
```

This is the default behaviour, and can be amended by including the following configuration in `server.properties` file

```
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
```

that essentially enables access to every user when no ACLs are configured.